# Does any trainer in the core Pokémon games use Unown?

Tags: pokemon-series

Do any trainers use Unown in their teams at all?
I define core as any Version [whatever] games. No console games count.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Yes, but it's unlikely you've ever met them.

You might be familiar with the [Trainer Hill](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Trainer_Hill) found in Pokémon Emerald, but it's a little known fact that connecting the [e-Reader](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/E-Reader) to a Japanese version of Pokémon Emerald lets you add trainers to the Hill based on which cards you've scanned. Two of [these trainers](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Emerald_(cards_41-48)_(Battle_e)), Pokéfan Francisco and Pokéfan Kimberly, can, depending on whether their cards were scanned first or second on a floor, battle using 3 different Unown each.

For the international release of Pokémon Emerald, Pokéfan Francisco and Pokéfan Kimberly can be fought on the 4th floor of the Trainer Hill's Variety Mode, where they will, again, both have a team of 3 Unown.

In Pokémon Crystal, Unown can be randomly fought in the Battle Tower's level 10 challenge, but it's never fought again in any other similar attraction in later games.

Comment: Really good find! I thought the answer might come from a battle frontier but this is even more unusual. I'll give the normal amount of time before accepting just in case there is other contributions.

Comment: Re: waiting to accept. You can always change the accepted answer, and accepting an answer won't prevent others from making their own answers. Just fyi

Comment: @Thomas however accepting an answer can discourage someone else from answering, so it's always good to wait a bit to accept, especially for more open ended questions like this one.

Comment: @Dragonrage very true. I only learned the other day about changing the answer and thought I'd share